# PDO::fetch() LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Do I need to write `LIMIT 1` using PDO's `fetch()` method? This assumes that I need only one result. I'm wondering, does using `LIMIT 1` will help to save resources and loading time?

Comment: Are you by chance downvoting every answer you receive? :-P

Comment: strictly speaking, PDO::fetch() can be used with multiple rows as well, using the while loop. and in this case adding limit 1 will be counter-productive

Answer (score 1):

The `LIMIT` clause is just one more SQL feature you can use to retrieve the information you need. Asking whether you need `LIMIT` cannot be answered unless you narrow your context. It's like asking if you need `WHERE` or `JOIN`. It depends on your data and your needs.

Not sure if that's what you have in mind, but I've seen projects where the developer was not fluent in SQL and just did the heavy lifting in application code, typically restricting their SQL to `SELECT * FROM table`. I think it's worthwhile to learn the basics of SQL so you're able to return the exact rows and columns you need. That's often a great boost for performance.